# SSRS Report: Barcode not rendering on browsers

Tags: browser, reporting-services

In my SSRS reports are there barcodes to display on the report.
Barcodes are generating perfectly fine in print preview, PDF, Word Documents.

The issue is the barcodes are not rendering on any of the Internet Browsers (Chrome, IE, Edge etc.).

Can someone please help me on this to fix the rendering issue.

Comment: Afreen I've had this issue in SSRS before, and many others have too. You'll want to provide more information about how you're rendering the bardcode (like if you're using an add-in or just a barcode font) and how the report is structured (if this is a subreport or a hyperlink etc.)

Comment: Hi Ryanman, I am using just the barcode font. This is a subreport.

Comment: Hi Ryanman, I am using this font : CarolinaBar-B39-2.5-50x158x720 to generate the barcodes.